# How to modify figure with subplots using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot

Whenever I'm making subplots, I'm used to making each plot individually and combining them all in a list.

Pandas is really cool because, with just one simple line of code, I can make a figure that contains histograms of all the features of a dataset:

```py
hist_plot = iris.hist(alpha=0.4, figsize=(10,6))
```

[image]

However, I'm stumped on how to make changes to this figure. For example:

- Making each plot a different color: `color = ['blue', 'red', 'green', 'purple']`
- Giving each plot a different title: `title = ['SLength', 'SWidth', 'PLength', 'PWidth']`
- Adding "Frequency" label to each y axis

**Is there a way to do this without having to make each plot individually?** I tried this as an example, but it didn't work:

```py
hist_plot = iris.hist(color = ['blue', 'red', 'green', 'purple'], alpha=0.4, figsize=(10,6))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`df.hist()` returns a two-dimensional array of axes objects, which correspond to the subplots in their grid arrangement. To iterate over them, their `flat` attribute is convenient, as it contains the same objects in a flat array. You can use `zip()` to iterate over the subplots and your color and title lists in parallel:

```py
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris

iris = load_iris(as_frame=True)['data']

colors = ['blue', 'red', 'green', 'purple']
titles = ['SLength', 'SWidth', 'PLength', 'PWidth']

axs = iris.hist(alpha=0.4, figsize=(10, 6))

for ax, color, title in zip(axs.flat, colors, titles):
    for patch in ax.patches:
        patch.set_color(color)
    ax.set_title(title)
    ax.set_ylabel('Frequency')
```

[image: Histograms of the iris data]